# QWebView's memory (cache) management

Tags: pyqt, qwebview, qwebkit, pyqt5

Here is the code that downloads the same page 10 times:

```
app = QApplication([])
event = threading.Event()

def load(url):
  def _load_finished(ok):
    event.set()

  web_view = QWebView()
  web_view.loadFinished.connect(_load_finished)
  event.clear()
  web_view.setUrl(QUrl(url));
  while not event.wait(.05): app.processEvents()
  web_view.loadFinished.disconnect(_load_finished)
  return web_view.page().mainFrame().documentElement()

QWebSettings.setMaximumPagesInCache(0)
QWebSettings.setObjectCacheCapacities(0, 0, 0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(10):
    load('http://www.huffingtonpost.com/')
    QWebSettings.clearMemoryCaches()
    QWebSettings.clearIconDatabase()
    print(i)
  app.exec_()
```

And here is Process Explorer's snapshot after 7th download:

[image: Memory increase from 50MB to 170MB]

At 10th download memory reaches 270MB. 
Is this normal? How do I fix it?

Oddly enough, depending on the address, consumption may fluctuate, but stay below certain threshold (here it's 90MB):

[image: Memory stays within 70..90MB]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have stumbled onto [this](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/11105/#159197) answer. Quoting [comment](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtwebkit/source/f5d7c6904da2dc5483bdfc202cb921b1c816f57a:Source/WebCore/loader/cache/MemoryCache.h#L65) in QT sources:

> 1. Dead resources in the cache are kept in non-purgeable memory.
> 2. When we prune dead resources, instead of freeing them, we mark their memory as purgeable and
>    keep the resources until the
>    kernel reclaims the purgeable memory.
>
> By leaving the in-cache
> dead resources in dirty resident memory, we decrease the likelihood of
> the kernel claiming that memory and forcing us to refetch the
> resource (for example when a user presses back).

This sort of settles it.. and relives my restless soul.

Following bms20's advice I run `QtWebKit` code in a separate process (using `subprocess.Popen`) and cache web resources on disk (`PyQt5.QtNetwork.QNetworkDiskCache`) to preserve traffic:

```
def ExecuteCode(code):
  import os
  os.environ['PYTHONIOENCODING'] = 'utf-8' #Optionally
  from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
  proc = Popen('python.exe', stdin=PIPE)
  out, err = proc.communicate(code.encode())
```

Part of `code` content:

```
cache = QNetworkDiskCache()
cache.setCacheDirectory('cache')
web_view = QWebView()
web_view.page().networkAccessManager().setCache(cache)
# Do stuff with web_page
```

Comment: Thanks for the question and answer. Is it possible to access to web_view object from main interpretator (to add it into layout)?

Comment: @user3479125, "main interpretator"==main program? If so, then I think not, because `code` runs in a separate process (via `Popen`). However, you can return the content of the page of the child process by printing it (the content) into the console. After the child process exits, content will be stored in `out`. Also, it seems that the whole QtWebKit is being replaced by [QtWebEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt5-intro.html#web-engine-and-html5). I have not tried it, but maybe there is no problems with memory consumption.